# ExpressJS: how to dump req.params from a global middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, middleware

I am not able to write a very simple middleware for ExpressJS that logs all req.params to console.
It seems that if I add the middleware to a specific function, it works, while the same code in an earlier app.use () does not get any data in req.params.

Here is an example code:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express();

// Simply log the req.params to console
const middle = ( req, res, next ) =>
{
    console.log ( "PARAMS: ", req.params );

    next ();
};

// Trying to access req.params in a global middleware does not work
app.use ( middle );

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})

// Specifying middleware in mount point works
app.get ( "/hello/:world", middle, ( req, res ) =>
{
    console.log ( "This works: ", req.params );
    res.send ( 'hello' );
} );

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: depending on which endpoint you hit you may not get anything but it should still be an empty object.  you wont get any if you hit `/` instead of `/hello/:world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working as global middleware because this param exists only in the url `"/hello/:world"`, and express won't know about this param till he runs this specific url middleware.

You can use `process.nextTick` to solve it.

```
const middle = ( req, res, next ) => {
    process.nextTick(() => console.log ( "PARAMS: ", req.params ));

    next ();
};
```

Comment: This works, but nextTick() is an async call and next() can be executed before the console.log.
This is a simple example and order doesn't really matter, but in a more complex example I should need the data before next() and it is not possible (I think).

Comment: You can't do it using express global middleware, but you can wrap your functions if you want